# "using" directives are available in inherited class in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class like this:

```
using System.Data;
public class A
{
    .....
}
```

And I am inheriting above class in class B. Do i need to declare `using System.Data` again here?

```
using System.Data; 
public class B: A
{
   .....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It takes much more time to type the question on SO than to try in VS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`using` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) have nothing to do with inheritance. They are hints for the compiler when parsing a cs file and are only valid within the context of that file.

For example, if you have the classes defined in different cs files, you need to have a `using` directive in each file, like this:

A.cs

```
using System.Data; 
public class A
{
   .....
}
```

B.cs

```
using System.Data; 
public class B: A
{
   .....
}
```

But if you have declared them in a single cs file, you only need one:

MyClasses.cs

```
using System.Data; 
public class A
{
   .....
}

public class B: A
{
   .....
}
```

It should also be noted that a `using` directive is only necessary if a class (or extension method) is used within that file, and don't want to use the fully qualified name of that class.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you do, assuming you follow the one-class-per-file guidelines of C#. A using-directive is  per source code file and is not inherited or otherwise transported across file boundaries:

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

> The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.